# Finding nodejs code examples that run without modification

Tags: node.js

I'm new to nodejs but have lots of programming experience elsewhere (perl, AppleScript)
I've been trying to educate myself about nodejs and have run up against several roadblocks because I've not been able to find a site which has functioning examples that I can play with.

Many sites post examples that won't run. Where can I find a good source of examples? ie those that compile.
For example - this does not compile ->

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// Run in the background (headless mode)
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

// Navigate to Google
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://google.com');

// Type "JavaScript" into the search bar
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').value = 'JavaScript';
});

// Click on the "Google Search" button and wait for the page to load
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(),
  page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('input[value="Google Search"]').click();
  })
]);

// Get all the search result URLs
const links = await page.evaluate(function getUrls() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a cite').values()).
    map(el => el.innerHTML);
});

await browser.close();
```

code is from from [https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/puppeteer]

problems with this code ->
running this in terminal on Mac with

> nodejs scriptname

returns errors ->

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

when I fix that,

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
             ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

I expected this script to run so I can try out some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript `await` will work if you put that inside `async` function calling like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    // Run in the background (headless mode)
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

    // Navigate to Google
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
    // Type "JavaScript" into the search bar
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelector('textarea[name="q"]').value = 'JavaScript';
    });

    // Click on the "Google Search" button and wait for the page to load
    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        page.evaluate(() => {
            document.querySelector('input[name="btnK"]').click();
        })
    ]);

    // Get all the search result URLs
    const links = await page.evaluate(function getUrls() {
        return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a cite').values()).
        map(el => el.innerHTML);
    });

    console.log(links);

    await browser.close();
})()
```

I have fixed your code so that works with this action:

1. Change `input[name="q"]` to `textarea[name="q"]` because Google Search use `textarea` as a container for searching text.
2. Change `input[value="Google Search"]` to `input[name="btnK"]` so that the search button will be clicked universally because if you switch language to non-English in your Google account, the value of input button will not be `Google Search`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that but when I try new things like that I end up going around in circles because my edit doesn't run and not knowing if I'm doing the right thing.

Comment: I'm checking out this now https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-puppeteer-with-nodejs/

Comment: After Jordy's edit, I get this --> 
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:57


Better find a different example

Comment: node v18 supports top-level await, you don't have to put it inside a function. https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce

Comment: That's funny, I have v19.7.0. The code from masterings.io (from the original question) still does not compile.